# TypeError: Unsupported only when writing to file not when printing

Tags: python, typeerror, writefile

I've written some code (below) which worked fine until i added a statement to write it to a file.

The error i get is TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float' which occurs on line 43.

What is confusing me is the fact that it doesn't throw this error when i use the exact same statements to print only when i write. I've looked through others with this error but can't work out whats going on in my case.

I've tried to break it down by each line to see if its prevalent through each write statement and it is.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great thanks.

```
import time

timeOfday = int((time.strftime("%H")))

if timeOfday < 11:
    meal = "Breakfast"
elif timeOfday >=11 and timeOfday <= 5:
    meal = "Lunch"
else:
    meal = "Dinner"

fileName = meal + " " + (time.strftime("%d%m%Y")) +".txt"

print "Hello, Please let us know how much your bill was"
billAmount = float(raw_input(">>"))

print "How much would you like to tip?"
tipAmount = float(raw_input(">>"))

print "How many people are paying?"
peopleAmount = float(raw_input(">>"))

if tipAmount > 1:
    tipAmount = tipAmount / 100

billAndTip = ((billAmount*tipAmount)+billAmount)
finalTip = (billAmount * tipAmount)
billDivided = (billAndTip / peopleAmount)

print "The total bill is %r" % (billAndTip)
print "Of which %r is the tip" % (finalTip)

if peopleAmount == 1:
    print"Looks like you are paying on your own"

else:

    print "Each Person is paying: %r" % (billDivided) 


target = open(fileName, 'w')
# target.write("The bill was %r before the tip \n You tipped %r% \n The total bill was %r \n Split between %r people it was %r each") % (billAmount, tipAmount*100, billAndTip, peopleAmount, billDivided)
target.write("The bill was %r before the tip") % (billAmount)
target.write("\n")
target.write("You tipped %r%") % (tipAmount)
target.write("\n")
target.write("The total bill was %r") % (billAndTip)
target.write("\n")
target.write("Split between %r people it was %r each") % (peopleAmount, billDivided) 
target.close()

print "This info has now been saved for you in the file %r" % (fileName)
```

Comment: You are trying to format the return of `write`. Move `billAmount` into the call parentheses

Comment: Thank you for the above comment, all working now. Few other errors to contend with but this is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the `%` sign here by making it a double-%:

```
target.write("The bill was %r before the tip \n You tipped %r%% \n The total bill was %r \n Split between %r people it was %r each") % (billAmount, tipAmount*100, billAndTip, peopleAmount, billDivided)
```

(Note `"You tipped %r%% \n"`.)

@LPK pointed out a bigger issue. Each of the lines like this:

```
target.write("You tipped %r%") % (tipAmount)
```

needs to be this:

```
target.write("You tipped %r%" % (tipAmount))
```

Comment: Hello i've tried the fix you provided but im still seeing the error as follows: <br>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc.py", line 43, in <module>
    target.write("The bill was %r before the tip") % (billAmount)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: @ImNewToThis Did you see LPK's comment, the other answer, and the edit I just made?

Comment: Hello, sorry did not refresh in time. This has fixed the error. Thanks ever so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
target.write("The bill was %r before the tip") % (billAmount)
```

Here you are using the `%` operator with the result of `target.write(...)`. `target.write(...)` returns `None` which is why the error is saying what it says.

Presumably you want to interpolate the bill amount into the string *before* passing it to `target.write(...)`. So do that!

```
target.write("The bill was %r before the tip" % (billAmount))
```

In other words, because you want to do the interpolation before the write, it goes inside the parentheses to the write call.

Comment: Hello Kindall, Thanks for the feedback your comment explained a lot alongside smarx's comment above. Every little helps!